# Django & App Engine - 2012 Refresh

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Before you close the topic, yes it's been asked before, but the last time was early 2010.

Are there any up-to-date efforts to use Django on GAE? Django-norel seems a little dated, along with its effort to get JOINs (and hence Many-to-Many, which I need). I haven't gone too far with Django, so if I'd save myself a headache by changing to a different framework that still has ORM, I'll accept that as a good answer too.

In the long run, I'm trying to run something with the ORM capabilities of Django, and the template capabilities of Django, on Google App Engine, so I'll take whatever solution meets my needs.

(For future readers, I ended up using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), and the Google App Engine's inbuilt datastore models.)

Comment: What's your objection to django-nonrel? What do you mean by "a little dated"?

Comment: It seemed a little dead before, and now I just found this: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/goodbye

Comment: "ORM" is misleading, since on App Engine there's no relational database to map objects to; the datastore stores objects.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but what about ORM abstractions? I know how I'd manually design a many-to-many on the system, but if I have to handle all that manually, I'll never actually finish this project.

Comment: Rumors of django-nonrel's demise are very much exaggerated. I expect it to be merged into upstream Django 1.5.

Comment: I fail to see how this question is 'Not Constructive', but I suppose the almighty voters know best. Interesting information @GuidovanRossum, I shall keep an eye on that, but Web2py looks like it'll give me what I'm after in the meantime.

Comment: The current home of django-nonrel is: http://django-nonrel.org/.  The allbuttonspressed page is obsolete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django-nonrel is not dated. Yes, former developers left the project, but it has been picked up and developed on github: https://github.com/django-nonrel

Basically you have 2 choices with running Django on GAE:
1. Use Django-nonrel and Google AppEngine's storage. Your data will be stored in a NoSQL database, which has its limits and advantages, but you can still mostly use Django's ORM classes.
2. Use regular Django and [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/django). Cloud SQL is basically MySQL in the cloud: it should be very familiar for most developers

Google Cloud SQL is currently in preview. You can use it for free, but your database size is limited to 10Gb. The FAQ says:

> We will not be billing for this service in 2011. We will give you at least 30 days’ advance notice before we begin billing in the future.

The pricing of AppEngine's Datastore is described [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/billing.html)

Comment: I didn't see it on Github, thanks for that. I ended up going for a smaller framework though.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's support for Django on Google App Engine currently. Check https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/django

Today, you need to make a request for a limited preview: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/before_you_begin

They took less than a week to answer my request.

Comment: What's the pricing on the cloud SQL?

Comment: Thanks, but seeing this is a project I'm developing, I couldn't answer their questions. I ended up using web2py, then Flask, anyway.

Comment: Google just released pricing for Cloud SQL: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing.

Comment: setting up Django to use Google Cloud SQL is actually very straight forward and IMO the new way to go - especially since django-nonrel is no longer maintained. Here's my beginner friendly tutorial how to set it up: http://howto.pui.ch/post/39245389801/tutorial-django-on-appengine-using-google-cloud-sql